# Unicode и Pythonanywhere

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot, python-3.6, unicode

**Сам код работает**, но когда ставлю задачу, чтобы он перезапускался в определённое время, пишет такие буквы:

```
UnicodeWarning:
Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
if msg == "начать":
```

Как я понял он не может сравнить эти значения, но в чём именно пролблема и как её исправить, понять не могу.

Comment: Похоже, что вы запускаете скрипт с помощью Python2, а не Python3

Comment: Вполне вероятно, но как проверить на какой версии запускается задача?
Сам же код на сервере работает на 3.8.

Comment: Смотря как запускаете. Если просто из командной строки, то обычно просто нужно помнить, что на Linux-системах просто `python` - это Python2, и нужно запускать командой `python3`

Comment: Ты пользовался pythonanywhere?
Задача сама перезапускается, а я не могу понять на каком именно python, т. к. там просто ничего нет.

Comment: Как она перезапускается - это не очень интересно. Куда вы ее вписываете, чтобы она вообще запускалась? Если через вкладку Tasks, там прямо в подсказке написано для примера python3.6 и путь к скрипту: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMg5C.png

Comment: Йоу, дружище, спасибо душевное, никак не мог понять как исправить это, видел что там написано, но никак не мог связать эти вещи :)